# Ejecutar un while por cada elemento de un arreglo

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

estoy utilizando la librería **moment js**

Estoy tratando de insertar fechas a un arreglo llamado *result* por ejemplo cada lunes, martes y miercoles entre una fecha de inicio y final, pero cuando trato de hacerles el push estos días al mismo arreglo sólo obtengo los de la primera posición (lunes) que tengo en el arreglo *days[]*

sospecho que el error está dentro del código que está entre ***

**¿Cómo podría darle push a los días dentro del mismo arreglo?**

Gracias de antemano

1 = lunes

2 = martes

...

7 = domingo

```
var start:Moment = moment(); // today
var end:Moment   = moment('2022-09-02');

days:number[]   = [1, 2, 3];  // monday, tuesday, wednesday 

function getDates(start:Moment, end:Moment, days:number[]) {
    // year, month, day
    
    let result:Moment[] = [];
    let current:Moment = start.clone();
    
    
    ***
    days.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
        while (current.day(7 + element).isBefore(end)) {
            result.push(current.clone());
        }
    });
    ***
    
    
    
    result.map(m => m.format('YYYY/MM/DD'))
    
    // result var with dates formatted to string
    let datesResult:string[] = result.map(m => m.format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
    console.log(datesResult);
}

getDates(start, end, days);
```

> resultado obtenido
> `['2022/08/15', '2022/08/22', '2022/08/29']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No veo la necesidad de usar [Moment](https://momentjs.com/), sobre todo cuando los autores recomiendan usar otras librería modernas. Moment se encuentra de cierta manera abandonada y ya no se actualiza, según reza en [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment):

> Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. In most cases, you should choose a different library.

Dicho esto, una forma de lograr lo que te propones podría ser de la siguiente forma, sin usar Moment o ninguna otra librería, simplemente Javascript. Y adaptarlo a Typescript es sencillo.

Por ejemplo, la función para obtener las fechas que se corresponden con los días de la semana que pasas en la lista se basa en simples matemáticas. Todo objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) de Javascript es en realidad una representación de la cantidad de milisegundos transcurridos desde la Época Unix, por lo cual, cada día se puede diferenciar de otro mediante un intervalo en milisegundos.

También tenemos que tomar en cuenta el problema de la zona horaria, ya que dependiendo de la misma, la fecha de un sistema puede ser equivalente a un día anterior o posterior de acuerdo a la fecha Unix.

Es por ello que podemos construir fechas en zona horaria neutra o Universal con el método [`UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC), que nos dará la cantidad de milisegundos transcurridos desde la Época Unix hasta la fecha que estamos construyendo.

La siguiente implementación construye 2 fechas (start y end) usando `Date.UTC`, luego mediante la comparación de su representación numérica se puede iterar entre dichas fechas y a la vez calcular el día de la semana de la fecha calculada en cada iteración. Si la lista de días contiene al día calculado, se hace el `push` a tu lista de fechas.

```js
const days = [1, 3, 5]; // monday, wednesday, friday

const start = new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 7, 1)); // 2022-08-01
const end = new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 7, 14));  // 2022-08-14

const getDates = (start, end, days) => {
  const dates = [];
  let s = start.valueOf();
  const e = end.valueOf();
  const interval = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
  while(s <= e) {
    const d = new Date(s);
    if(days.includes(d.getDay())) {
      dates.push(d);
    }
    s += interval;
  }
  return dates;
}

const dates = getDates(start, end, days);
console.log(dates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**Nota**

Recordemos que los argumentos pasados al método `UTC` en este caso son numéricos y el valor que corresponde al mes se entiende iniciado en 0 y va hasta 11. Siendo 0 el correspondiente a Enero y 11 a Diciembre.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me fue de mucha ayuda, quedó resuelto mi problema